# Pasting URL in @misc entry for bib

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, url

I have written the following entry for a URL in `ieeetr` bib style:

```
@misc{Microsoft18,
 title={Introducing the Office (2007) Open XML File Formats},
 url={https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338205(v=office.12)},
 urldate={15-August-2018)},
}
```

The result is the shown below:

```
[3] “Introducing the office (2007) open xml file formats.”
```

No URL and no date are shown.

UPDATE: The code for that is:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{The title}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle


\subsection{sample}
Office-2007~\cite{Garfinkel09,Microsoft18}.
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibs}
\end{document}
```

The file `bibs.bib` contains `@misc` which I pasted above.

I use TexWorks, where I run PDFlaTeX->BibTex->PDFLaTeX->PDFLaTeX.

What should I do?

Comment: Which options do you pass to `biblatex`?

Comment: In the question body you mention `IEEE-tran` (which is a BibTeX style), but your question is tagged with `biblatex`. There is `biblatex-ieee` for `biblatex`, but you can't use `IEEEtran.bst` together with that package. Can you please clarify which package/bibliography method you use? Ideally you would do that in an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: `ieeetr` is really old. Did you try the newer `IEEEtran`? (As recommended in the  `IEEEtran` docs: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf pt. XIII.C)

Comment: @moewe: OK. Thanks. I got it from `http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtranS.bst`. However, `urldate` seems to be an invalid parameter because url is shown but not the date.

Comment: Try to add the visiting date in field `note={...}, `